# JQuery Mobile checkbox not responding to .on('vclick')

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling

I'm working on a JQM app and I'm trying to have a checkbox reveal extra options when pressed.  I'm pretty used to using $().on('vclick') to capture my events, but it doesn't seem to work with checkboxes.  Any idea why?

A fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/T3qmG/43/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h2>Checkbox Test</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-choice-1" />
                <label for="checkbox-choice-1">Click me</label>
        </div>
        <input id="vclick-test" type="button" value="A normal button"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkbox-choice-1").on('vclick', function(){
        alert("VClick event triggerd.  Yet you'll never see this..");
    });
    $("#checkbox-choice-1").click(function(){
        alert("Click event triggerd.");
    });
    $("#checkbox-choice-1").change(function(){
        alert("Change event triggerd.");
    });
    $("#vclick-test").on('vclick', function(){
        alert("This proves that vclicks do work...");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that inputs with `[type=checkbox]` and `[type=radio]` accept `click`, `change` and `tap` only.

However, if you still want to use `vclick` then you need to bind this event to the `label` of the input.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LpdUz/)**

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-choice-1" />
<label for="checkbox-choice-1">Click me</label>
```

**JS**

```
$("[for=checkbox-choice-1]").on('vclick', function () {
  alert("VClick event triggerd. Yet you'll see THIS..");
});
```